# I am trying to get 3 conditions in one if . But it's not working

Tags: javascript

I need to match three conditions so that the page can show the appropriate result for that filters. I tried adding the && between three of the conditions but it doesn't work.
I am not revealing the real code here, but I've shown it without the original var names.

```
if(localStorage.getItem("eg1") == 30000 &&  eg2 == 1 &&   eg3 == use){};
```

eg2 and eg3 are just variables, they are not localstorage.

Comment: Shouldn't `eg2 == 1` be `ocalStorage.getItem("eg2") == 1`? And I suspect the same for `eg3`.

Comment: Please check if `localStorage.getItem("eg1")` is actually returning something.

Comment: @VLAZ Sorry I didn't understand

Comment: @rombie18 it is showing the results when I do not have multiple conditions

Comment: Console your local storage items and their types. Usually they all will be stored as string if used raw so you will be having comparison between string and numbers i.e., "30000" == 30000

Comment: Consider creating a method to return a bool which would do your checks, this is getting a biut messy.

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan there is no type check, 3000 == '3000' is valid. typecheck would require `===`

Comment: I know that but we don't know what's actually in his local storage

Comment: The local storage is storing a number itself. I've used the local storage because I had to get the value across multiple html pages.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
if((localStorage.getItem("eg1") == 30000) && (eg2 == 1) &&   
(eg3== use)){};
```

Comment: All of them are not local Storage . Only the first one is and other all are variables

Comment: Oh, Did you check whether all the variables give value using console log before the condition?

Comment: Try this and check whether output comes in  the developer mode `console.log(localStorage.getItem("eg1") );` `console.log(eg2);` `console.log(eg3 );`

Comment: All of the variables and the local storage is also working I have checked, also is there any problem with my code. The if was working when I only had the local storage condition. but when I put in the the other conditions with the variables the if did not show any results

Comment: @VishalPillai Try adding brackets to separate 3 conditions as above, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit cleaner way to do it:

```js
const a = ["eg1", "eg2", "eg3"].map(e => localStorage.getItem(e));

if (a[0] == 30000 && a[1] == 1 && a[2] == use) {
  //
}
```

And a less dynamic but shorter way to do it:

```js
if ([30000, 1, use].map((e, i) => e == localStorage.getItem("eg" + i++)).includes(false)) {

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your code. I am not an advanced javascript writer. I have only started last year.

Answer (score 0):

Try to decompose the problem in order to analyze it better:

```
var e1 = localStorage.getItem("eg1") === 30000;
var e2 = eg2 === 1;
var e3 = eg3 === use;
```

I've used triple equal since i suppose you don't want type coercion.

Since you can't show the original code, if you don't put some log of your results it's quite difficult to imagine what variables can contain with appropriate level of certainty.

Sure is that looking to your conditions independently should help you to identify where your guesses fall to fix what appears as a simple branch condition.

Comment: It's not an idea, you're here because you can't figure out how to getting work a simple 3 conditions if statement shortcircuited. I'm just trying, without having access to your informations, to help you reason once a time, on your problem. You're welcome

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be rude. I was afraid somebody would get the idea of my website from the code.

Comment: I didn't say the don't copy my idea to you. I said that generally

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage.getItem` returns the value as string.

Try using  `if(localStorage.getItem("eg1") == "30000" &&  eg2 == 1 &&   eg3 == use){};`